# Format table from output of a string

Tags: powershell, format, tabular

I have tried different ways but not able to format data into table

```
$str1 = "First string"
$str2 = "Sec string"
$str3 = "third str"
$str4 = "fourth string"

$str = "$str1 $str2 `r`n"
$str+= "$str3 $str4"

write-host $str | Format-Table
```

I am looking to create output like below:

```
First string  Sec string 
third str     fourth string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `Format-Table` as intended, you need *objects with properties* rather than mere strings:

```
$str -split "`r`n" | ForEach-Object {
    # Initialize a custom object whose properties will reflect 
    # the input line's tokens (column values).
    $obj = New-Object PSCustomObject; $i = 0
    # Add each whitespace-separated token as a property.
    foreach ($token in -split $_) {
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName ('col' + ++$i) -NotePropertyValue $token
    }
    # Output the custom object.
    $obj
  } | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

- `` $str -split "`r`n" `` splits the multi-line string into individual lines and sends them through the pipeline one by one.
- The `ForEach-Object` command constructs a custom object from each line whose properties are the whitespace-separated tokens on the line, as described in the comments; the property names - which don't matter for the output - are auto-generated as `col1`, `col2`, ...

  - **Note**: This does *not* match your desired output exactly in that ***each* space (run of whitespace) is treated as a separator**. If you wanted to treat the original `$str1`, `$str2`, ... variable values (e.g., `First string`) each as a *single* column value, you'd have to make *assumptions* about how to tokenize the line.
    For instance, **if the assumption is that *2 consecutive words* form a single value**, replace `-split $_` above with `$_ -split '(\w+ \w+) ?' -ne ''`
  - **If you didn't want to rely on *assumptions***, you'd have to **construct your input strings with *embedded quoting*** so as to unambiguously indicate token boundaries (the code would then have to be modified to parse the embedded quoting correctly).
- `Format-Table` then displays the custom objects in tabular form, with columns properly aligned; `-HideTableHeaders` suppresses the header line (the auto-generated property names).

With your sample input, the above yields the following, produced *without* `-HideTableHeaders` so as to better illustrate what the code does:

```
col1  col2   col3   col4
----  ----   ----   ----
First string Sec    string
third str    fourth string
```

Ditto, but with the 2-consecutive-words splitting logic:

```
col1         col2
----         ----
First string Sec string
third str    fourth string
```

---

As for what you tried:

- Do not use `Write-Host` to produce *data* output: `Write-Host` output (by default) goes to the *console* and *bypasses the pipeline*, so that `Format-Table` receives no input and has no effect here.
- That said, even if `Format-Table` *did* receive input (by using `$str` by itself, *without* `Write-Host`, i.e.: `$str | Format-Table`), it would have no (visible) effect on *strings*, which are *always rendered as-is*.